# preg_replace Removing unwanted strings (official clip, official video clip, official video etc.)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to remove unwanted strings from name.

- `(official)? (music|lyric(s)?)? (clip|video|videoclip|video clip)`:

> - official music video **OR**
> - official lyric video **OR**
> - music video **OR**
> - official videoclip **OR**
> - lyrics video **OR**
> - official clip **OR**
> - official video  **etc.**

- (clipe|video|videoclipe|video clipe) oficial:

> ```
> /(v(i|í)deo\s?)?(clipe?)? (no )?oficial/iu
> ```

- oficjalne (video|wideo):

> ```
> /(nie)?oficjalne (v|w)ideo/i
> ```

- oficjalny (clip|film|klip|teledysk|videoclip):

> ```
> /(nie)?oficjalny (film|odsłuch|teledysk|trailer|((v|w)ideo\s?)?(c|k)lip|zwiastun)/iu
> ```

Could you help me create regular expression for this combination?

- full movie hd **OR**
- full video hd **OR**
- full movie **OR**
- full video **OR**
- full hd **OR**
- hd

`(full)? (movie|video)? (hd)?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified:

`(official|music|lyrics?|clip|video|video\s?clip)\s?`

for:

- official music video
- official lyric video
- music video
- official videoclip
- lyrics video
- official clip
- official video

And

`(full|movie|hd|video)\s?`

for:

- full movie hd
- full video hd
- full movie
- full video
- full hd
- hd

Comment: Ok, but if I have the name "Malines - Blockbuster [full hd]" it is replaced to "Malines-Blockbuster". Whitespaces also are removed.